# Data as tidy as possible after gather function

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I am trying to get data in the tidyiest format possible.

Originally, it looked like this:

```
applicants_wide <- tibble::tribble(
  ~fiscal_year,          ~job_number,                 ~job_description, ~total_applications, ~Female, ~Male, ~Unknown_Gender, ~Black, ~Hispanic, ~Asian, ~Caucasian, ~American.Indian..Alaskan.Native, ~Filipino, ~Unknown_Ethnicity,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,      20,    31,               3,     25,        18,      1,          6,                                0,         0,                  4,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,     488,   152,               8,    151,       204,    123,         62,                                3,        79,                 26,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,      13,    37,               1,      8,        12,      9,         20,                                0,         0,                  2,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,       9,    38,               1,     21,        14,      3,          7,                                0,         1,                  2,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,      15,    24,               1,      3,         7,      7,         19,                                1,         1,                  2,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,      89,    66,               6,     12,        36,     20,         73,                                0,         6,                 14
  )
```

Then I created two columns using dplyr's `gather`: `gender` and `ethnicity`.

```
#Put data in the tidy format
applicants_long <- applicants_wide %>%
  gather(key = "gender", value = "gender_count", -c(8:14, 1:4)) %>% 
  gather(key = "ethnicity", value = "ethnicity_count", -c(1:4, 12:13))
```

That led me to have this:

```
applicants_long
# A tibble: 126 x 8

tibble::tribble(
  ~fiscal_year,          ~job_number,                 ~job_description, ~total_applications,          ~gender, ~gender_count,                        ~ethnicity, ~ethnicity_count,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,         "Female",            20,                           "Black",               25,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,         "Female",           488,                           "Black",              151,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,         "Female",            13,                           "Black",                8,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,         "Female",             9,                           "Black",               21,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,         "Female",            15,                           "Black",                3,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,         "Female",            89,                           "Black",               12,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,           "Male",            31,                           "Black",               25,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,           "Male",           152,                           "Black",              151,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,           "Male",            37,                           "Black",                8,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,           "Male",            38,                           "Black",               21,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,           "Male",            24,                           "Black",                3,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,           "Male",            66,                           "Black",               12,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54, "Unknown_Gender",             3,                           "Black",               25,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648, "Unknown_Gender",             8,                           "Black",              151,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                           "Black",                8,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                           "Black",               21,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                           "Black",                3,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161, "Unknown_Gender",             6,                           "Black",               12,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,         "Female",            20,                        "Hispanic",               18,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,         "Female",           488,                        "Hispanic",              204,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,         "Female",            13,                        "Hispanic",               12,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,         "Female",             9,                        "Hispanic",               14,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,         "Female",            15,                        "Hispanic",                7,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,         "Female",            89,                        "Hispanic",               36,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,           "Male",            31,                        "Hispanic",               18,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,           "Male",           152,                        "Hispanic",              204,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,           "Male",            37,                        "Hispanic",               12,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,           "Male",            38,                        "Hispanic",               14,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,           "Male",            24,                        "Hispanic",                7,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,           "Male",            66,                        "Hispanic",               36,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54, "Unknown_Gender",             3,                        "Hispanic",               18,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648, "Unknown_Gender",             8,                        "Hispanic",              204,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                        "Hispanic",               12,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                        "Hispanic",               14,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                        "Hispanic",                7,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161, "Unknown_Gender",             6,                        "Hispanic",               36,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,         "Female",            20,                           "Asian",                1,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,         "Female",           488,                           "Asian",              123,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,         "Female",            13,                           "Asian",                9,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,         "Female",             9,                           "Asian",                3,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,         "Female",            15,                           "Asian",                7,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,         "Female",            89,                           "Asian",               20,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,           "Male",            31,                           "Asian",                1,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,           "Male",           152,                           "Asian",              123,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,           "Male",            37,                           "Asian",                9,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,           "Male",            38,                           "Asian",                3,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,           "Male",            24,                           "Asian",                7,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,           "Male",            66,                           "Asian",               20,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54, "Unknown_Gender",             3,                           "Asian",                1,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648, "Unknown_Gender",             8,                           "Asian",              123,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                           "Asian",                9,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                           "Asian",                3,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                           "Asian",                7,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161, "Unknown_Gender",             6,                           "Asian",               20,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,         "Female",            20,                       "Caucasian",                6,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,         "Female",           488,                       "Caucasian",               62,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,         "Female",            13,                       "Caucasian",               20,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,         "Female",             9,                       "Caucasian",                7,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,         "Female",            15,                       "Caucasian",               19,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,         "Female",            89,                       "Caucasian",               73,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,           "Male",            31,                       "Caucasian",                6,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,           "Male",           152,                       "Caucasian",               62,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,           "Male",            37,                       "Caucasian",               20,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,           "Male",            38,                       "Caucasian",                7,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,           "Male",            24,                       "Caucasian",               19,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,           "Male",            66,                       "Caucasian",               73,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54, "Unknown_Gender",             3,                       "Caucasian",                6,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648, "Unknown_Gender",             8,                       "Caucasian",               62,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                       "Caucasian",               20,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                       "Caucasian",                7,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                       "Caucasian",               19,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161, "Unknown_Gender",             6,                       "Caucasian",               73,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,         "Female",            20, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,         "Female",           488, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                3,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,         "Female",            13, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,         "Female",             9, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,         "Female",            15, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                1,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,         "Female",            89, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,           "Male",            31, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,           "Male",           152, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                3,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,           "Male",            37, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,           "Male",            38, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,           "Male",            24, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                1,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,           "Male",            66, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54, "Unknown_Gender",             3, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648, "Unknown_Gender",             8, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                3,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51, "Unknown_Gender",             1, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48, "Unknown_Gender",             1, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40, "Unknown_Gender",             1, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                1,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161, "Unknown_Gender",             6, "American.Indian..Alaskan.Native",                0,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,         "Female",            20,                        "Filipino",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,         "Female",           488,                        "Filipino",               79,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,         "Female",            13,                        "Filipino",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,         "Female",             9,                        "Filipino",                1,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,         "Female",            15,                        "Filipino",                1,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,         "Female",            89,                        "Filipino",                6,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,           "Male",            31,                        "Filipino",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,           "Male",           152,                        "Filipino",               79,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,           "Male",            37,                        "Filipino",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,           "Male",            38,                        "Filipino",                1,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,           "Male",            24,                        "Filipino",                1,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,           "Male",            66,                        "Filipino",                6,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54, "Unknown_Gender",             3,                        "Filipino",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648, "Unknown_Gender",             8,                        "Filipino",               79,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                        "Filipino",                0,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                        "Filipino",                1,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40, "Unknown_Gender",             1,                        "Filipino",                1,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161, "Unknown_Gender",             6,                        "Filipino",                6,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,         "Female",            20,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                4,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,         "Female",           488,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",               26,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,         "Female",            13,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,         "Female",             9,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,         "Female",            15,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,         "Female",            89,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",               14,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54,           "Male",            31,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                4,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648,           "Male",           152,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",               26,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51,           "Male",            37,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48,           "Male",            38,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40,           "Male",            24,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161,           "Male",            66,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",               14,
   "2013-2014", "9206 OP 2014/04/18",              "311 DIRECTOR 9206",                  54, "Unknown_Gender",             3,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                4,
   "2013-2014",  "1223 P 2013/08/09",          "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",                 648, "Unknown_Gender",             8,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",               26,
   "2013-2014", "7260 OP 2014/02/14",           "AIRPORT MANAGER 7260",                  51, "Unknown_Gender",             1,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",  "3227 P 2013/11/15", "AIRPORT POLICE LIEUTENANT 2013",                  48, "Unknown_Gender",             1,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",  "2400 O 2014/05/02",                  "AQUARIST 2400",                  40, "Unknown_Gender",             1,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",                2,
   "2013-2014",               "1191",                  "ARCHIVIST1191",                 161, "Unknown_Gender",             6,               "Unknown_Ethnicity",               14
  )
```

But something doesn't feel right... Tidy data has one observation per row and here the columns `gender_count` and `ethnicity_count` are summarising several observations in a row.

If I want to get data in the *tidyest* format possible, have I done everything I can or am I missing a step?

Comment: If I'm understanding it right, you can't really tidy this data because you don't know how many people there were in the *combinations* of gender and ethnicity. You could make one dataset that is "tidy" for gender counts, and a separate one that is "tidy" for ethnicity counts I think, but not both.

Comment: Can you show what output do you expect?  If the data is too big make a smaller example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tidy because the observations (i.e. *rows of values*) are distinct, but that doesn't mean the relationship between each individual observation's values is meaningful. The problem is that the original data tells us, for example, how many women and how many blacks applied, but it doesn't tell us how many black women applied. That means the ethnicity breakdown for each gender within a job description will be identical – e.g. the count for "Black" will be 25 for "Women", "Men", and "Unknown_Gender" for the job description "311 DIRECTOR 9206".

You can probably still work with this data in tidy format, but I think grouping, summarizing, etc. would be unnecessarily circuitous. It would probably make more sense to split the data into two tidy dataframes: One for gender and one for ethnicity.